# Using an IF function to refer to separate sheet

Tags: excel, if-statement

[EXCEL] I am looking for a way use an IF function that refers to a column that is referring to a sheet.

EX:
[image]

NOTE: *yellow box is what I want to have happen using the function*

The **ID** column is populated from a separate sheet in my workbook
Formula:

`=Sheet2!$A$3:$A$48`

`=Sheet3!$A$3:$A$48`

I want the **Flag** column to refer to the **ID** column from the other worksheet. In pseudocode:
"*If ID field references the Sheet2 Range, return value 1, ELSE, return 0*".

Comment: What is the expected result under Flag? 1, 1, ...?

Comment: for this case it would either be a 1 or 0

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Edited my question, is it now clear?

Comment: You could use `FORMULATEXT` and `FIND` perhaps. Would help if you specified which of Excel or Google Sheets. They are similar but not identical and approaches may differ based on which of the two you're actually using.

Comment: I highly suggest that you share a sample sheet for us to have a sample data to work on and to verify the possible solution we could provide [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383). I'm not sure if my understanding is correct that you want to check if the id in `ID` column exist in the range of ID column that you mentioned? `=Sheet2!$A$3:$A$48`

Comment: In addition, please clarify if you expect an excel solution or a google sheets solution

Comment: Question is for Excel

Comment: @RonM I want to check if the `ID` column exists in the range, and if it does, then return 1 in the `Flag` column. If it does NOT, return 0 in the `Flag` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @BigBen's comment try this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Sheet2",FORMULATEXT(A2))),1,0)
```

replace `A2` with cell reference that matches the location of ID # 123456 in your spreadsheet, and then drag the formula down.